# What does xCode color scheme item "Attributes" stand for?

Tags: xcode, themes, xcode5

Working on an xCode color scheme, but I just can't make **Attributes** work.
It actually does not tint `__attribute__` statements.

[image]

```
// Not this.
NSString a* __attribute__((visibility("default")));
// Nor this.
__strong NSString *b;
// So what?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's used with XML markup. You can see the applied attribute color by opening a storyboard as source code instead of interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

```
// Declare the availability of a particular API
void f(void) __attribute__((availability(macosx,introduced=10.4,deprecated=10.6)));
```

something good to read about it [**attribute**](http://nshipster.com/__attribute__/)

Comment: I thought the same, but this just don't get that color in editor.

Comment: Useful read but not in any manner an answer to the question. This should have been posted as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @mah well the question asked for an example of __attibute__ the link was there for reference, anyway you are free of downvote as you just did

Comment: @elio.d I agree the title did say that but reading the question would have made it clear that the title wasn't well written. You'll find many titles on this site are poorly written / non-descriptive of what is being asked.

Comment: Wow. I think no one will ever open this question with such title. Anyway, it is maybe an xCode bug. I think all __block, __strong, and __attributes__ as well should be colored with that slot. But actually it does not.